# JavaScript Regex for explicitly selecting item between two groups?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string such as the the below;

> foo function name () foo

I wanted a regular expression that can match all characters (including white-space) 
between the two groups `function` and `(`.

That is,  I want a regular expression that only matches "name" in the string "foo function name () foo"

I have tried using regex code like;

```
\function(.*?)\(\g
```

but it seems to return `function name (`

I did a demo here https://regexr.com/4le5h

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're using JS, you have the capture group in the result--why not use that? `(?<=function\s).+?(?=\s*\()` works in PCRE but not JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive lookbehind to match `function`.

```
(?<=function +)[^ ]+
```

- `(?<=function +)` = look for something following "function" and one or more spaces
- `[^ ]+` = match anything that is not a space one or more times

Matches "name" in your example.

https://regex101.com/r/euqBSk/4

Comment: that (look behind) does not work in edge, actually.

Comment: ***on side note:-*** but will not work with string which has  more then one space before name i.e. `function   name()` since in your character class you have `[^ ]+`, IMO `[^(]+` will be a better choice, anyways just an edge case

Comment: You might omit the capturing group around the character class.

Comment: @CodeManiac Good call, I updated it to account for that

Answer (score 2):

If your enviroment doesn't support lookaround as some of browser doesn't at present you can simply use capture group and get desired value from that

[image]

```js
let str = "foo function name () foo"
let matched = str.match(/\bfunction\s*([^(]+)\s*\(/)

console.log(matched[1])
```

If you're working on environment which does support or lookarounds then you can simply do

```js
let str = "foo function name () foo"
let matched = str.match(/(?<=\bfunction\s*)([^(]+)(?=\s*\()/)

console.log(matched[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could search for not whitespace and opening bracket, followed by some whitespace and an opening bracket.

```js
var string = 'foo function name () foo',
    match = string.match(/function\s+([^\s)]+)(?=\s*\()/)[1];

console.log(match);
```